# Can I use "bottom line" as "fundamental point"?

Tags: word-usage

bottom line in English has 2 meanings:

> 1- the final total of an account, balance sheet, or other financial
>   document. "the determination of Japanese companies to ignore the
>   bottom line" synonyms:    profit, net, gain, earnings, return "how will
>   the move affect our bottom line?"
>
> 2- the underlying or ultimate outcome or criterion. "the bottom line is
>   I'm still married to Denny"

(Source: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+bottom+line)

My question is that:

Can I use "bottom line" as "fundamental point"?

For example, "**The bottom line (the fundamental point) is that you need to work hard**". In this case, "`the bottom line`" does not actually mean "`the ultimate outcome`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American English, using "the bottom line" in that way would be perfectly understandable.

The [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bottom-line) defines "the bottom line" as " the most basic fact or issue in a situation," which seems to apply in this situation.

Comment: I would say that was true in other English too: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bottom-line

Answer (score 0):

You may use it. The bottom line in an account is seen as the most concise summary of all above it. By analogy, you may use the bottom line to mean the most concise summary of all your preceding argument.